# how to prevent the writerow method to iterate through a string

Tags: python, date, csvwriter, string-iteration

I want to write a string to a csv using `writerow` but the result I'm getting is not what i want

```
def date_csv():

    date_str = pd.Timestamp.today().strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    print(date_str)   ### output: 16-04-2022
    with open("Alert_date.csv", "a", newline="") as file:
        writer_object = writer(file)
        writer_object.writerow(date_str)
```

csv file result:

```
1,6,-,0,4,-,2,0,2,2
```

what i want:

```
16-04-2022
```

Comment: If you "row" only has one field, why bother with a CSV writer? Just use `file.write(date_str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow` writes an iterable in a single line, with each item separated by the separator.

A string is an iterable, so the result of `writerow('abc')` is `a,b,c`.
If you want to write a string as a single element you can put it inside another iterable, like a list: `writerow(['abc'])` -> `abc`